# Regex - How two characters matching (MySql)

Tags: mysql, regex

Please find my query below.

```
SELECT * FROM demoTable WHERE C_APPLICATION_REF_NO REGEXP '[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{0,14}';
```

why i am getting result which having two character whereas i am matching only one character and others are numbers.

[image]

how to modify my regex expression so that i can only fetch one character and others are numbers.

Comment: You match all records where one character is followed by Zero up to 14 number. But you never say that bevor the character sould not be an other char

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that your regex is not anchored to the start/end of string, and thus partial matches are returned, too.

Use

```
REGEXP '^[A-Z][0-9]{0,14}$'
```

`{1}` is redundant.

Comment: i tried with this too. [A-Z][0-9]{0,14}. Anyway got the reason.

Comment: if i remove end($) from regex it again matches two characters. Any reason why? This time it looks fine with no end of String. like start with Only one character immediate next would be digit. @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: The `$` is the end of string anchor, if you remove it, the pattern will find a match `A` in `AB` because the `[0-9]{0,14}` allows matching an empty string (zero digits). You must use anchors here.

Answer (score 0):

This query should work.

```
SELECT * FROM demoTable WHERE C_APPLICATION_REF_NO REGEXP '^[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{0,14}$';
```

Comment: Of course, it is exactly what I have already suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This help you :

```
 var patt =/^[A-Z]{1,}[0-9]{0,14}$/g;
```

Or

```
 var patt =/^[A-Z][0-9]{0,14}$/g;
```